# HTML translate attribute doesn't work with styled-components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I want to avoid my component's contents to get translated by Google translate. For that, I am trying to use `translate="no"` using styled-components's `attr` as below but it doesn't work:

```
const MyComp = styled.div.attrs(props => ({
   name: props.id,
   translate: props.translate,
}))`
padding: 0;
`

<MyComp id="some-id" translate="no"></MyComp>
```

The `name` property is working fine but `translate` property is not working. Is there any other way to disable the translation?

Comment: Is `props.translate` always `"yes"` or `"no"`? Could be passing `undefined` as a prop value, so you might want to default `translate: props.translate || "no"`.

Comment: @Nathan, I tried setting default value. Also while debugging, `props.translate` is truthy, but it doesn't work.

Comment: If that's the case, you'll need to convert the truthy value to `"yes"` or `"no"`: `translate: props.translate ? "yes" : "no"`. Additionally some browsers do not support the `translate` attribute [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/translate). For google translate react specifically you may also want to include `className="notranslate"` in your components.

Comment: That too doesn't work. However, `className="notranslate"` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

There is a issue for that in styled-components github:

https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/pull/3619

if you use yarn would could do this work around:

add this in to your package.json

"resolutions": {
"styled-components/@emotion/is-prop-valid": "^1.1.0"
}